# I am trying to make a program which will take a number and display the prime number before and after it

Tags: java, loops, primes

I am trying to make a program which will take user input as an integer and will display the prime number before it and after it. I cannot see what I have done wrong as the output is nothing. It would be great if somebody could help!

```
package prime;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prime
{
    boolean flag = false;
    public boolean isPrime(int x)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= x/2; i++)
        {
            if (x % i == 0)
            {
                flag = true;
                return flag;
            }  
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] abc)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an number. A prime number preceeding and succeeding that number will be displayed.");
        int num = sc.nextInt();

        Prime p = new Prime();

        for (int j = num;j < num && j > 0;j--)
        {
            if (p.isPrime(j-1) == true)
            {
                System.out.println("Prime number predeceeding " + num + " : " + j);
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int j = num;j > num;j++)
        {
            if (p.isPrime(j+1) == false)
            {
                System.out.println("Prime number succeeding " + num + " : " + j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why is it `i <= x/2` in your for loop?

Comment: The above code should not even compile. The isPrime() method requires a final return false statement. So please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. It does not make sense to show us code that "prints nothing" when in reality, that code is not going through the compiler!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified working code.

Made some changes:-

1.Initialized flag to true and if we find any factor just return false.

2.For finding a greater prime number just start an infinite loop from num+1. But do make sure that the input number is within the Integer value bound i.e 65535.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prime
{
    boolean flag = true;
    public boolean isPrime(int x)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < x/2; i++)
        {
            if (x % i == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }  
        }
        return flag;
    }
    public static void main(String [] abc)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an number. A prime number preceeding and succeeding that number will be displayed.");
        int num = sc.nextInt();

        Prime p = new Prime();

        for (int j = num-1; j > 0; j--)
        {
            if (p.isPrime(j))
            {
                System.out.println("Prime number predeceeding " + num + " : " + j);
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int j=num+1; ;j++)
        {
            if (p.isPrime(j))
            {
                System.out.println("Prime number succeeding " + num + " : " + j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer boils down to a code drop without any explanation. That is generally not appreciated here.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition on both the for loops will evaluate to false. In the first case:

```
for (int j = num;j < num && j > 0;j--)
// for(initialization; test-condition; updation)
```

The test condition is false in the first iteration because you have initialized `j` to `num` and you are now checking if `j < num` which is false. Hence, it never goes into this loop.

Similarly, in the second case:

```
for (int j = num;j > num;j++)
```

you have initialized `j` to `num` and are now checking if `j > num` which is obviously false. Hence, the content of this loop is also never executed.

You can correct these by changing the initialization part in both the for loops (as suggested by [@zenwraight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50727453/3160529)):

```
for(int j = num-1; j > 0; j--) // first case
for(int j = num+1; ; j++)      // second case
```